# document.click keep toggling the menu

Tags: jquery, html

I have this simple header menu but when i click `#nav li` ,the `#nav ul` keeps toggling.I want to hide `#nav ul`  if clicked anwhere else on the document.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#nav li').click(function() {
      $('ul', this).show('fast');
    });

     $(document).click(function() {
        $('ul','#nav li' ).hide('fast');

    });

  });
```

Here is the  Simpe HTML. http://jsfiddle.net/pMaL5/

```
 <div id="nav">

    <li style="margin-top: -15">
        <a class="modalbox"  href="#header2_li" style="font-size: 40px;">ADD</a>
        <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="modalbox" href="#inlineheadersend">Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>News</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span href="#">Messages</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="modalbox" href="#inlineheadersend">compose new</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>show messages</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>


</div>
```

Comment: @roasted i have added HTML in my question.Plz review now

Comment: This HTML doesn't make sense, you have `<li>`s that are not inside an `<ul>`. Please fix your HTML

Comment: It is very unclear what you expect to click and show up or disappear. Please write a better explanation of which item is supposed to be clicked and what is going to get hidden/displayed

Comment: @JuanMendes its very simple when NAV first child li's are clicked,then li's of u1 are shown.

Comment: @CutyPie Do not kid your self that what you wrote previously is clear, it's not.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle with VALID HTML? Thank you

Comment: @roasted See my answer for my best guess as to what the OP needs

Answer (score 3):

Events bubble up, so when you click a `li`, you implicitly also click the `document` (because `document` is a ancestor of the `li`). You can prevent that with `e.stopPropagation()`:

```
$('#nav li').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: This would work but could break other behavior that did need those click events at the document level. I prefer to add a handler at the document that checks that the click didn't come from that UI

Comment: @JuanMendes thanks.it worked.could you plz attach an handler on this code as an expamle?

Comment: @CutyPie What??? I have nothing to do with that. I could show you an example if you post your HTML

Comment: @JuanMendes ,your solution stopped fancy box to work now.Plz suggest any alternative approach.thanks

Comment: @CutyPie Then post your HTML, are you even reading all the comments on your question?

Comment: @JuanMendes i have added HTML in my question.Plz review

Comment: @CutyPie Did this answer not properly address your question? Is it still not working?

Comment: @JuanMendes it is working.but clashing now with fancybox.as fancybox does not appera  after using stop propagation

Comment: @CutyPie Then this should not be marked as the accepted answer. pimvdb is under the impression that the answer they provided works fine

Comment: @CutyPie As Juan mentioned, why do you accept an answer that doesn't works? This is non-sense as all your thread...

Comment: @Juan Mendes   Ya, im afraid about that

Comment: @CutyPie Your comments sound like a robot! Did you even read my answer? You should be able to modify your code from my example. If not, ask a specific question. Asking "Please fix my code for me" is **VERY** rude

Comment: @JuanMendes i asked question and comented  with humble request.I do appologise if anyone percieved my comments as VERY RUDE.Your code(.stop propagation) works fine,becoz the manu works properly.but it interfers with the fancybox(dont let it open).

Comment: @CutyPie I did not suggest you use `stopPropagation()`, I pointed it out to you that using it could be troublesome. Your question is a mess... why are you asking me questions under someone else's answer? You sound like you think I wrote this answer. Re-read my answer (not this one), study the code I posted. If that doesn't work, or if you have a hard time applying it to your code, explain what is not working or which part you're having a hard time with (under my question).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is what pimvdb mentioned. Every click propagates to the document (unless you call `stopPropagation()`).

The problem with pimvdb mentioned (calling `stopPropagation`) is that there may be other handlers relying on your clicks going all the way to the document. Which is what it looks like is happening  with fancybox

I've modified your HTML to make more sense and be simpler to read. Your previous HTML was setting handler on all `li`s but it should only be doing it to the first one. I added some class names to make your HTML more semantic, relying on tag names is poor practice

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="add"><a class="modalbox">ADD</a></li>     
    <li>
        <span href="#">Messages</span>
        <ul class="showhide">
            <li><a class="modalbox" href="#inlineheadersend">compose new</a></li>
            <li><a>show messages</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8s6wJ/1/

The following script does what you need to the above HTML without preventing the click from propagating.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav').click(function() {
        $('.showhide').show('fast');
    });

     $(document).click(function(e) {
         // Only hide if actual element clicked 
         // was not a child of #nav
         if ($(e.target).closest('#nav').length == 0) {
             $('.showhide').hide('fast');
         }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thats seems ok, but i really dislike to bind event to document

Comment: @roasted There is no other way?? This way is guaranteed not to affect anything else because of how you're filtering the document click handler

Comment: See my answer for an other way, not sure its really better though

Answer (score 1):

This is an other way, without binding anything to document:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav').click(function() {
        $('.showhide').show('fast').focus();
    });

    $('.showhide').focusout(function(e) {
         $(this).hide('fast');
    }).focus();
});​
```

See  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8s6wJ/2/)  based on Juan Mendes answer

Comment: Yes, that is another way... I think slightly more hackish than what I suggested, but works. However, it would only work in the context of something that is focusable like a link. +1

Comment: @Juan Mendes   By setting an tabindex attribute, you can focus any DOM element i think. In my example, i do it with an ul.

Comment: That's true, it does work in IE8+ and other browsers http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/tabindex  The main difference is that your solution works if you tab out, but it may not be the correct behavior since there are other links in `#nav` and we wouldn't want to hide the div in that case. The solution I used is what `Ext-JS` uses for dismissing menus when clicking somewhere else on the screen

Comment: @Juan Mendes   Ok, i get your point of view, thanks for the input

Comment: By the way, I actually think this would be a great solution if you don't have other focusable items and you do want the popup to go away when you tab out, didn't want that to get lost in my comments about problems